# Can this be the right polynomial fraction even tho f(0) does not match the solution

Tags: polynomials, fractions

From a rational function in the form $ f(x)= \frac{p(x)}{q(x)} $ the following is known.

The numerator polynomial has double zeros $x_{1,2} = 2 $ and a single zero $x_{3} = -2 $ The denominator polynomial has a simple zero at x = -1 and x = 3. Furthermore $ f(0) = - 8$

Im susposed to find out what the function looks like in the as above stated form. My attempt;

$$ f(x) = \frac{(x-2)^2(x+2)}{(x+1)(x-3)} $$ Simplify both nummerator and denominator

$$ f(x) = \frac{x^3-2x^2-4x+8}{x^2-2x-3} $$ This is my final polynomial; the zeros are correct; finding the zeros of the numerator and denominator I get the ones stated in the question. But when I try to check for f(0) I do not get -8. This is what I get

$$f(0) = \frac{8}{3} $$ If I put 0 for all the x's in the numerator and denominator.

Does this mean my function is wrong,or is the way im checking for f(0) is wrong? I am not sure what I am missing here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Knowing the roots (plus multiplicity) of a polynomial only determines it up to a constant multiplier.  Note:  and it doesn't even do that unless you are working over an algebraically closed field like $\mathbb C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to give an example: If $3$ is a root of say $p(x)=x-3$, then $3$ is also a root of $q(x)=cp(x)=c(x-3)$ for every constant $c$. What you're missing is that, it is not necessary for all polynomials to be monic to have particular roots. So you can multiply by some unknown constant either the numerator or the denominator, and find it afterwards.

Comment: Ahaaa okay I see,so what I need to do is find a constant $ c $ that when I multiply my f(x) I get -8, so I need to multiply everything with -3?

Comment: I think from your calculations $f(0)$ has to be $-\frac{8}{3}$, so in that case, you will have to multiply by $3$ the numerator polynomial, or by $\frac{1}{3}$ the denominator polynomial. The roots of either polynomial, will not change.

Comment: Ah yes its $-\frac{8}{3} $ silly mistake on my part,than we need to multiply with 3 obviously.Thanks for the help! Cheers.